# How to stop for loop running all at once

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I am currently practising with for loops with array lists. Each time the user gets an answer correct an extra random value is added to the sequence. So at the start one image flashes, each time one more image flashes in sequence.

The problem I am have is that the whole sequence plays at once. For example on the second run two images should flash, one then the other. But what I currently get is both flash together. How can I break up the loop so one will flash and then the other.

my code is below:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int retval;  

    public void Run(){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(5)+ 1 ;       
        list.add(rndInt);
        int totalElements = list.size();

        for(int i=0; i < totalElements;i++ ){ 
            retval = list.get(i);

            if  (retval==1){

                Centre.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash1);
                Reset.start();// runs a class that resets the imageiew after a few seconds 
            }

            else if (retval==2){

                upperRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash2);
                Reset.start();
            }

            else if (retval==3){

                lowerRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash3);
                Reset.start();
            }

            else if (retval==4){    

                lowerLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash4);
                Reset.start();
            }

            else if (retval==5){
                upperLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash5);
                Reset.start();      
            }   
        }
    }
```

EDIT

```
CountDownTimer Reset = new CountDownTimer(1000 , 0010){ 
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {      
        }
        public void onFinish() {        
            Centre.setImageResource(R.drawable.i1);
            upperRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);
            lowerRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
            lowerLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.i4);
            upperLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.i5);              
            }
        };
```

Comment: `break up the loop so one will flash and then the other.` Do you mean change the image resources? Why are you using `Reset.start(); ` to "reset" the resource, where is the source code?

Comment: the reset is just a timer, it so after a few seconds it puts the image resource back to what it was before the for loop was ran.

So yes by flash I mean to set the image resource as it does in the code provided

Comment: I few things here, that "timer" most likely runs in another thread and this loop only runs `totalElements` times(most likely on the main thread) therefore it will not be in sync with the timer. You said you want the images to `two images should flash, one then the other. `

Comment: under the edit I have added the reset. I have tried moving it inside the for loop but it changed nothing. If the pause in the for loop can be put in I feel the reset will work as intended.

Comment: Your timerclass is resetting all pictures. I don't really see a good reason for it. But setup this way I would introduce a hasStopped function in the Reset.class and add directly after each Reset.start() a do while !Reset.hasStopped() {} so your code will wait and continue flashing the next pic after the previous has been reset.

Comment: the timer class resets all so I can have just the one reset not mattering what image has changed. I understand what you are saying, but I am having trouble implementing it. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Ok so I've tried another method, using animation drawable instead of my reset method. the same problem happens. The problem definitely is because the numbers are all read at once instead one at a time. can any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the fix incase anyone wants to show images in a sequence:

```
public void ZAP() { 
            if(i < totalElements){

                retval =list.get(i);

                if  (retval==1){                
                check = 1;              
                Centre.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash1);
             ResetTimer.start();        

            }       
            else if (retval==2){

                check = 2;          
                upperRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash2);                     
             ResetTimer.start();

            }   
            else if (retval==3){

                check =3;   
                lowerRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash3); 
                 ResetTimer.start();    

            }   
            else if (retval==4){

                check = 4;      
                lowerLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash4); 
                 ResetTimer.start();

            }   
            else if (retval==5){

                check=5;
                upperLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash5);  
                 ResetTimer.start();
            }}

            }
    public void Rand() {
            i=0 ;


        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(5)+ 1 ;       
        list.add(rndInt);
         totalElements = list.size();
     Log.d("LOOK", Integer.toString(rndInt));
     Log.i("VALUE LIST ", list.toString()+" <<<<LIST HERE"); 
     ZAP();
```